# Automator: Move files into new subfolder based on file's name

Tags: finder, applescript, bash, automator, file-transfer

Disclaimer, this may not be something Automator can do.

I have a large directory of movie files. In order to use a piece of software, each movie needs to be in it's own folder. I'd like to create some sort of automation to do the following:

- Create folders named after each filename `ex: Cool Movie.m4v =>  Cool Movie ƒ`
- Move movie file to corresponding folder

I'm hoping that between Automator, Bash, or AppleScript, there's a way to do this.

Clarification:

If I have a folder that looks like this:

1. Movies ƒ

   - Movie A.m4v
   - Movie B.m4v
   - Movie C.m4v

I'd like it to look like this after:

1. Movies ƒ

   - Movie A ƒ

     - Movie A.m4v
   - Movie B ƒ

     - Movie B.m4v
   - Movie B ƒ

     - Movie B.m4v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Terminal**, *change directory* to the *folder* containing the *files*, e.g.:

```
cd /path/to/files
```

Then use the following *compound command* to do what you've asked:

```
for f in *.*; do [ -f "$f" ] || continue; mkdir "${f%.*}" && mv "$f" "${f%.*}"; done
```

If you want to limit it to just `.m4v` *files*, then change `for f in *.*;` to:
 `for f in *.m4v;`

Note that this doesn't make a *folder* with the `ƒ` character you've shown, but if it's part of the wanted *folder name*, then change both occurrences of `"${f%.*}"` to: `"${f%.*} ƒ"`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question and with the help of wch1zpink came up with this solution. In automator:

1. create a new workflow
2. add get selected finder items
3. add run applescript
4. replace the script with this:

   ```
   tell application "Finder"
       set selectedFiles to selection as alias list
       set containingFolder to container of item 1 of selectedFiles as alias
       repeat with i from 1 to count of selectedFiles
           set thisItem to item i of selectedFiles
           set fileName to (text items 1 thru -5) of (name of thisItem as text) as string
           move thisItem to (make new folder at containingFolder ¬
               with properties {name:fileName})
       end repeat
   end tell
   ```